# c / c++ programming what is a uid composed out of an int and an index?

Tags: c++, variables, scripting, uid

can someone explain this line of code to me?

```
#define reference_uid(id,idx) ( (int64) ((uint64)(id) & 0xFFFFFFFF) | ((uint64)(idx) << 32) )
```

I understand this is supposed to be a unique identifier. but I'm not sure what actually happens here :(

an example for its use:

```
mapreg->setreg(reference_uid(script->add_str("$@bg_member"), count), sd->status.account_id);
```

mapreg is a global variable storage, that's supposed to be accessible from external scripts. here the variable name will be $@bg_member
$ stands for global where 
@ defines the scope - with @ meaning that the variable is unique to the current instance of a script.

I'm wondering if this is just a way to define $@bg_member as array. or whether this allows to store multiple copies of $@bg_member within the mapreg with their unique ids.

But because I don't know that. I don't know how to properly adress them from script either :(

edit: I should probably mention, that script->add_str("$@bg_member") returns the id of the variable and remains the same. where as count is increased within a for loop on each rotation.

Comment: There's no c/c++ language.

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language.

Comment: Read about bit masking and bit shifting please.

Comment: well true. I was just not sure how to adress it. 
The code I'm working with contains a wild mix of c++ and c classes

Comment: Are you using both `c` and `c++` compilers for different parts?

Comment: no i think c parts are marked with Extern C so I suspect it's c++ compiled

Comment: The opening question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the discussion that follows.

Comment: Well it looks like the macro places the `idx` number in the `4` most significant bytes of a `64 bit` integer (`id`) while preserving the `4` least significant bytes of that same integer.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not introduce "C parts", i.e. compile as C code! It only changes the ABI and interface like name-mangling to C compatibility. Code will still be C++ code!

Comment: does it even matter how this is compiled? 
@Galik so this is sort of used as an offset?